# Does the improper integral $\int_{R^2} \frac{\ln(x^2+y^2)}{x^2+y^2}$ converge?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, improper-integrals

Does the improper integral $\int_{R^2} \frac{\ln(x^2+y^2)}{x^2+y^2}$ converge?

So I know to solve such integrals when the function is all positive, but here it can be also negative.

I tried using the definition $\int f  =\int f^+ - \int f^-$ and calculate for each part.

When I try for $f^-$, that means for { $x^2+y^2 <1 $ } I get to the integral (after using polar coordinates) $$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(r^2)}{r}dr$$ which goes to $- \infty$.

While the same integral for $f^+$ goes to $\infty$.

Does that mean the the original integral goes to $\infty$ ? From what I remember either the integral for $f^-$ or $f^+$ has to converge for the integral to be defined.

Another direction which I thought would be calculating the integral for  $$\int_{R^2} \frac{|\ln(x^2+y^2)|}{x^2+y^2}$$ and since it is less than $$\int_{x^2+y^2 > 1} \frac{|\ln(x^2+y^2)|}{x^2+y^2}$$ then it must not converge.
Am I right here?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The last part I am not sure on, as the last integral you've written does converge... the problematic point is at $(0,0)$, where, indeed, the integral fails to converge.

Comment: Are you sure it does not converge? I can use polar coordinates and the integral would be $\ln^2(\infty) - \ln^2(1)$

Comment: @GabiG: maybe think back to $1$ dimensional improper integrals. Those are defined by taking the integral on finite pieces and then taking the limit. You need to take separate limits for each singularity. You can't just cancel $\infty$'s willy-nilly.

Comment: But since the function (with the absolute value) is positive if I can show that at one singularity it doesn't converge that it won't converge generally, or am I mistaken here?

Comment: Since both $\int f^+$ and $\int f^-$ are infinite, the integral $\int f$ does not exist as in Lebesgue-integral sense.

Comment: Ah yes my bad, none of these integrals converge! x.x (and I just finished calc III too >.<)

Comment: Yeah, I'm taking calc III now. Does my second method in the question prove divergence of the integral?

Comment: @GabiG Yes if it fails to converge at one singularity, you're done. It doesn't converge.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost right. Let us do the calculation in a bit detailed way

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\ln(x^2+y^2)}{x^2 + y^2}dxdy = 2\pi\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\ln r^2}{r}dr = 4\pi\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\ln r}{r}dr$

Now, using variable transformation of $\ln r = u$, we obtain
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\ln(x^2+y^2)}{x^2 + y^2}dxdy = 4\pi \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}u du$$

If you are strictly speaking in the context of elementary calculus, then yes the integral does not converge. However, the Cauchy Principle Value of the integral exists and it tends to zero. You might want to look for Cauchy Principle Value.

Comment: Well, in the sense of what I learned, even if $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}u du$ exists but $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|u| du$ doesn't, then we say it doesn't converge